# GCC .data Section Changes

Tags: c++, gcc

I recently created two executables from the exact same source code and the exact same path on my computer using GCC version 2.9-gnupro-98r2. When I do a binary compare of the two executables there are differences in the .data section of the executable. Does anyone know why this would happen? I need to produce a consistent executable every time.

Thanks!

Comment: You _have_ a consistent executable. Why do you need an _identical_ executable?

Comment: Consistent is defined as "unchanging". Since my executable changes I therefore do not have a consistent executable. I need to be able to produce an identical/consistent executable for work-related reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to timestamp information in the executable.  If any of your sources use the `__TIME__` macro, the binary executables will be different if you compile at different times.

Comment: After further investigation and comparing my link maps I found the difference in my executables was caused by a path to a temporary folder being included in the debug information of my executable. After stripping the debug information from the executable they are the same. The `__TIME__` macro is useful information but I had already checked for that in my code (I should have specified that in my questions). Thanks for the answer though!